# How can I declare an array with diffrent type of data?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, types

[image]
[image]

```
Private Function DataPreparation()
    'DateTime detail
    Dim dateFrom As Date = dtp_dateFrom.Value.ToShortDateString
    Dim dateTo As Date = dtp_dateTo.Value.ToShortDateString
    Dim timeFrom As Date = dtp_timeFrom.Value.ToShortTimeString
    Dim timeTo As Date = dtp_timeTo.Value.ToShortTimeString

    Dim detail() = {ContainItemID, ApItemType, dateFrom, dateTo, timeFrom, timeTo}
    Return detail
End Function
```

Why array convert my dateFrom to string? How can I keep diffrent datatype in array?

Comment: i think unless you declare an array as an object you cant get different datatypes in the same array...try declaring the array in the object class then try assigning it values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array can't contain different **Datatypes**.

If you want to store and return the values there are two solutions:

**1. Convert all the values to same datatype**

You could convert all your values to an array of **String**

```
Dim MyArray() As String
```

**2. Create an Object**

You could create an object for instance:
(This isn't the exact code you need I think is better you try to figure out the datatypes you need and will help you the most to create a useful object.

```
Public Class Dater
    Dim dateFrom As Date
    Dim dateTo As Date
    Dim timeFrom As String
    Dim timeTo As String
End Class
```